# How to click dynamic<li> element in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click 4th list element which is expanded in below html code.

The xpath is every time same as `//*[@id='filter_result_totals']/ul/li[4]/a`

The element value **1946** is always changing, it's representing as count of records.

```html
<document>
<html>
<head>
<body style="overflow-y: hidden;">
<div class="container">
<div id="header" class="header">
<div class="main-menu menu menu-left">
<div class="headercontent">
<div style="display: none">
<div class="finder">
<div id="profile" class="profile menu">
<div class="clear"/>
<div class="main-toolbar">
<div class="main-toolbar-title">List view</div>
<div class="main-toolbar-subtitle">
<div class="main-toolbar-info">
<div id="filter_result_totals">
<ul>
<li class="extra_toolbar_category">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a class="query_link" href="/monitor/index.php/listview?q=%5Bservices%5D%20state!%3D0%20and%20acknowledged%3D0%20and%20scheduled_downtime_depth%3D0%20and%20host.scheduled_downtime_depth%3D0%20and%20state%3D2%20and%20has_been_checked%3D1" data-query="[services] state!=0 and acknowledged=0 and scheduled_downtime_depth=0 and host.scheduled_downtime_depth=0 and state=2 and has_been_checked=1" title="Services critical">
<span class="icon-16 x16-shield-critical" title="Services critical"/>
1946
</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main-toolbar-buttons toolbar-buttons">
<div class="clear"/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page_settings" class="page_settings">
<div id="content" class="content " tabindex="0" style="height: 605px;">
<div class="jq-notify-zone"/>
<script type="text/javascript">$.notify.sessionid = '9723b1738ffd58a3a48627f3f4a39e6bad230cd2';$.notify.configured = {};</script>
</div>
<ul id="property_menu" class="contextMenu">
<ul id="svc_property_menu" class="contextMenu">
<div id="fancybox-tmp"/>
<div id="fancybox-loading">
<div id="fancybox-overlay"/>
<div id="fancybox-wrap">
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: none;"/>
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: none;">
<div id="AutocompleteContainter_1485854680035" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; top: 36.7667px; left: 1353.13px;">
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Any Error you getting ?

Comment: Hi Narendra..  thanks for your response. yes am getting 'no such element: Unable to locate element' always. i have tried with xpath and also absolute path.  a2.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result_totals']/ul/li[4]/a")).click();

Comment: can you try this `     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result_totals']/ul/li[4]/a"));
     JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: yeah...i have tried am getting below error.invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='filter_result_totals']‌​/ul/li[4]/a because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='filter_result_totals']‌​/ul/li[4]/a' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: How about link `title`: is `"Services critical"` unique value?

Comment: What is `a2` in `a2.findElement`?

Comment: can you replace this `xpath` - `//li/a[@class='query_link'][@title='Services critical']` and try

Comment: no, title is not unique value. its different for each li element.

Comment: a2 just my driver name.

Comment: yeah have tried...getting same error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li/a[@class='query_link'][@title='Services critical']"}.. @ Narendra

Comment: is there  `iFrame` in your document ?

Comment: Try this Xpath
 //a[@title='Services critical']/span[@title='Services critical']

Comment: thank you all.. i got solution. after use explicit wait , its working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It might be timing issue. Try to set implicit wait

```
a2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or use explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(a2, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result_totals']/ul/li[4]/a")));
element.click();
```

See [waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: Hi. thanks for your response. its not working. because for every li element class name is 'query_link'.

Comment: @JegaB Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='query_link'][title='Services critical']")).click();
```